# Writing an excel formula or VBA macro that returns the number of a certain type of calls made in a week/month/past 60 days/past 90 ays

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a sheet that's updated throughout the day that list three types of calls that are made in a day: cold, return, update. The data for each type of call is stored in its own sheet in one Excel file via external connections to the data sources. For each call made, the date is recorded.

I need to make a table that shows how many of each type of call is made today, in the past week (business days only), the past month, and at this same time from the past month.

I have the following formula that allows me to return all the calls of a particular type that happened today, but and having trouble including a range of dates. I tried to make a formula for that too, but it doesn't work.

*The formulas shown below are only for cold calls. I will adjust the formulas for returns and updates.

Formula to retrieve number of calls today (works fine):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type],{"Cold"},MTD_Calls_Made[Date],TODAY()))
```

Formula to retrieve number of call made over a range of dates (doesn't work):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type], {"Cold"}, MTD_Calls_Made[Date],TODAY()-1),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-2),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-3),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-4),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-5),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-6),COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type][Date],TODAY()-7))
```

Comment: Thank you both for the responses! The explanations are very helpful and I got the formula to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple function that would technically work

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"cold",B:B,">=" &NOW()-30)`

simply replace the `A:A` with the column location of the 'status' (i.e. cold, return, update). and then replace the `B:B` with the column location of the 'Date' the status was updated. Lastly, replace the "cold" for the status you wish to search.

edit: I forgot to mention, replace the `30` at the end of the formula with the correct time frame you want to capture (i.e. 30 = average month, 60 = 60 days, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SUM()` function is redundant in your first formula, as `COUNTIFS` will return a single number, so you can eliminate that. Additionally, I can't imagine you actually need those brackets in there.

Now, to answer your question the `criteria` parameter of `COUNTIFS` assumes an `=` operator if none other is specified. In order to use `COUNTIFS` for a range of dates, you need to add some operators and high/low boundaries:

```
=COUNTIFS(MTD_Calls_Made[Type],"Cold",MTD_Calls_Made[Date],"<=" & TODAY(),MTD_Calls_Made[Date],">=" & TODAY()-7)
```

This would get you the total count of `"Cold"` between today and 7 days ago.